# Java String to Date object of the format "yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss"

Tags: java, string, date, simpledateformat

I need to convert a String containing date into an date object. The String will be of the format "yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS" and I want the same format in an date object.

For instance I have a string "2012-07-10 14:58:00.000000", and I need the resultant date object to be of the same format.

I have tried the below methods but, the resultant is not as expected.

```
java.util.Date temp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS").parse("2012-07-10 14:58:00.000000");

DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss");
                Date thisDate = dateFormat.parse("2012-07-10 14:58:00.000000");
```

The result is "Tue Jan 10 14:58:00 EST 2012". Please let me know where I am going wrong.

Thanks,
Yeshwanth Kota

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 & Java 9. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: @Yeshwanth, the reason is Your not applying Date formator

Answer (score 61, accepted):

```
java.util.Date temp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS").parse("2012-07-10 14:58:00.000000");
```

The `mm` is minutes you want `MM`

**CODE**

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        java.util.Date temp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS")
                .parse("2012-07-10 14:58:00.000000");
        System.out.println(temp);
    }
}
```

Prints:

> Tue Jul 10 14:58:00 EDT 2012

Comment: when i parse the date "2021-03-02 17:30:41.624862" with java.util.Date temp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS").parse("2021-03-02 17:30:41.624862");  i get output as Tue Mar 02 17:41:05 IST 2021, which is wrong? right?
around 11 minutes ahead.
why is that

Comment: Incorrect Answer. A `java.util.Date` object is limited to milliseconds. Microseconds are not supported.

Answer (score 11):

For future reference:

```
 yyyy => 4 digit year
 MM   => 2 digit month (you must type MM in ALL CAPS)
 dd   => 2 digit "day of the month"

 HH   => 2-digit "hour in day" (0 to 23)
 mm   => 2-digit minute (you must type mm in lowercase)
 ss   => 2-digit seconds
 SSS  => milliseconds
```

So "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" returns "2018-01-05 09:49:32"

But "MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm a" returns "Jan 05, 2018 09:49 am"

The so-called examples at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html show only output. They do not tell you what formats to use!

Comment: FYI, the troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class has been outmoded for years by the java.time classes built into Java 8 & 9. Specifically, [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html). The old date-time classes bundled with the earliest versions of Java should be avoided.

Answer (score 3):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDateTime.parse( 
    "2012-07-10 14:58:00.000000".replace( " " , "T" )  
)
```

## Microseconds do not fit

You are attempting to squeeze a value with microseconds (six decimal digits) into a data type capable only of milliseconds resolution (three decimal digits). That is impossible.

Instead, use a data type with fine enough resolution. The *java.time* classes use nanosecond resolution (nine decimal digits).

## Unzoned input does not fit a zoned type

You are attempting to put a value lacking any offset-from-UTC or time zone into a data type (`Date`) that only represents values in UTC. So you are adding information (UTC offset) not intended by the input.

Use an appropriate data type instead. Specifically, [`java.time.LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html).

## Case-sensitive

Other Answers and Comments correctly explain that the formatting pattern codes are case-sensitive. So `MM` and `mm` have different effects.

## Avoid legacy classes

The troublesome old date-time classes bundled with the earliest versions of Java are now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes built into Java 8 and later.

## ISO 8601

Your input strings nearly comply with the ISO 8601 standard formats. Replace the SPACE in the middle with a `T` to comply fully.

The java.time classes use the standard formats by default when parsing/generating strings. So no need to specify a formatting pattern.

## Date-time objects have no "format"

> and I need the resultant date object to be of the same format.

No, date-time objects do not have a "format". Do not conflate date-time objects with mere strings. Strings are inputs and outputs of the objects. The objects maintain their own internal representions of the date-time info, the details of which are irrelevant to us as calling programmers.

## java.time

Your input lacks any indicator of offset-from-UTC or troublesome me zone. So we parse as a `LocalDateTime` objects which lacks those concepts.

```
String input = "2012-07-10 14:58:00.000000".replace( " " , "T" ) ;
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input ) ;
```

## Generating strings

To generate a String representing the value of your `LocalDateTime`:

- Call `toString` to get a String in standard ISO 8601 format.
- Use `DateTimeFormatter` for producing strings in either custom formats or automatically-localized formats.

Search Stack Overflow for more info as these topics have been covered many many times already.

## `ZonedDateTime`

A `LocalDateTime` does *not* represent an exact point on the timeline.

To determine an actual moment, assign a time zone. For example noon in Kolkata India comes much earlier than noon in Paris France. Noon without a time zone could be happening at any point over a range of about 26-27 hours.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone( z ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - [**Java 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) brought some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android (26+) bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the process of [*API desugaring*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring) brings a [subset of the *java.time*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) functionality not originally built into Android.

    - If the desugaring does not offer what you need, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above) to Android. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score 2):

Your not applying Date formator. rather you are just parsing the date. to get output in this format

```
yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS
```

we have to use format() method here is full example:-
Here is full example:-
it will take Date in this format `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS`
and as result we will get output as same as this format `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS`

```
 import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

//TODO OutPut should LIKE in this format yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS.
public class TestDateExample {

public static void main(String args[]) throws ParseException {

    SimpleDateFormat changeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS");

    java.util.Date temp = changeFormat.parse("2012-07-10 14:58:00.000000");
     Date thisDate = changeFormat.parse("2012-07-10 14:58:00.000000");  
    System.out.println(thisDate);
    System.out.println("----------------------------"); 
    System.out.println("After applying formating :");
    String strDateOutput = changeFormat.format(temp);
    System.out.println(strDateOutput);

}

}
```

[image: Working example screen]

Answer (score 0):

its work for me
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
sdf.format(new Date));